# Web3 0.20 contract deployment

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, infura, sendrawtransaction

environment: Web3 0.20.7,Infura,node.js(backend)
Deploy contract with Web3 0.20.7

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Bang{
    address holder;
    address proxy;
    constructor (address _holder, address _proxy) public {
        holder=_holder;
        proxy=_proxy;
    }
    function getholder() public view returns(address){
        return holder;
    }
}
```

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var Web3 = require('web3');
const testnet = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/';
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(testnet));
var wallet_address = "0x4b2194Fa5a.....";
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_address);
var data = "0x608............"//from remix detail
var holder = "0xF2C44b7f10533....";
var proxy = "0xf21BF631C5382....";
var rawTransaction = {
  "from": wallet_address,
  "nonce": web3.toHex(count),
  "gasPrice": web3.toHex(5000000000),
  "gasLimit": web3.toHex(5000000),
  "data": data
};

var privateKey = new Buffer('CEA8070A7EC5........', 'hex');
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);

tx.sign(privateKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), 
  function(err, hash) {
    if (!err)
        console.log(hash);
    else
        console.log(err);
});
```

These codes would deploy that contract,but the constructor argument cannot be into the contract. How to insert the constructor argument in web3 0.20.7 with infura?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Constructor argument shall be part of the `data`. A quick check to see if you have prepared the correct data is to check if the two addresses that you would pass to the constructor is part of `var data = "0x608............"//from remix detail`

If you don't like the hex data, you could use the `web3.eth.Contract.deploy` method to pass constructor parameters as an altenative solution. An example could be found in the documentation [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy).